# Shapefiles are not lining up

Tags: coordinate-system

I have two shapefiles with the same projection, but they could not overlay each other. I understand that the extent is different, but I could not figure out how to change it.

Here are the two layers properties:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the projections are different. The first one in WGS84 and the second is in meter maybe in UTM Zone 36 since the landuse is located in Kenya. Try to project the first one to UTM projection. and see if they overlay each other. You may need to re-define the projection of the second one to UTM, if necessary.

Comment: it is still just the same, both layers are not overlaying

Comment: How did you define the spatial reference of the second one? Its extent compared cannot be in WGS84 projection.

Comment: The second one looks like UTM zone 37 South. Redefine it using the Define Projection tool or the data's property page in ArcCatalog.

Comment: @mkennedy thanks a lot, that has solved the problem.